# User defined renderer object causes a TypeError - marked.js

Tags: javascript

Right now I'm familiarizing myself with *marked.js*. I want to add html attributes to the elements that are rendered when `marked.parse()` is called. In doing so a custom `renderer` object has been defined which overrides the `code` method.

When the `renderer` object is passed to `marked.parse(string, {'renderer': renderer})`, and I start typing in the `TextArea` that *marked.js* is supposed to parse the following error is raised:

- `Uncaught TypeError: t.text is not a function`

https://marked.js.org/using_pro#renderer

> The renderer defines the HTML output of a given token. If you supply a renderer object to the Marked options, it will be merged with the built-in renderer and any functions inside will override the default handling of that token type.

What is causing this error to be raised?

```
const renderer = {
  code(code, infoString) {
    return `
      <code class="block_code_snippet fill_block_width">${string}</code
    `
  },
};
```

```
post_content_body.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
  let marked_post_content = marked.parse(
    post_content_body.value, {"renderer": renderer}
  );
  post_preview.innerHTML = marked_post_content
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the renderer object passed in is not merged with the default renderer, but replaces it completely. As a result, the renderer only handles code, but loses all other rendereing capabilities - see "Block-level renderer methods" and "Inline-level renderer methods" [here](https://marked.js.org/using_pro#renderer).

Try changing your code to something like:

```js
const renderer = new marked.Renderer();
renderer.code = function(code, infoString) {
  return `
    <code class="block_code_snippet fill_block_width">${string}</code
  `
};
```